# Variadic template arguments by reference

Tags: c++

How can I make this template function variadic :

```c++
template <typename T>
void checkedAlloc(size_t count, T*& x) {
  x = new T[count]();
  if(nullptr == x){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: not enough memory (%llux%llu bytes).\n\n", count, sizeof(T)); 
    exit(1);
  }
}
size_t *A; checkedAlloc(20, A);
```

so as to be able to do :

```c++
size_t *A, *B, *C; checkedAlloc(20, A, B, C);
```

?

**Solutions:**

*C++17*: [Dani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362589/dani)

```c++
template <typename ...T>
void checkedAllocV(size_t count, T*& ...x) {
    ((checkedAlloc(count, x)), ...);
}
```

*C++14*: [mch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3684343/mch)

```c++
void checkedAlloc(size_t count) {}
template <typename T, class ... Ts>
void checkedAlloc(size_t count, T*& x, Ts&& ...args) {
  try { x = new T[count](); }
  catch (const std::bad_alloc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory (%zux%zu bytes).\n", count, sizeof(T)); 
    exit(1);
  }
  checkedAlloc(count, args...);
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<size_t> a(20), b = a, c = a;` instead?

Comment: Thank you. I mostly want to know how/if it can be done.

Comment: `new` will throw an `std::bad_alloc` on allocation failure, it won't return `nullptr`.

Comment: mch's answer satisfies my curiosity. But as per  NathanOliver's suggestion, vectors are so much easier to use and safer. Unless you allocate for a library/API function (like WideCharToMultiByte) that doesn't accept a vect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename ...T>
void checkedAllocV(size_t count, T*& ...x) {
    ((checkedAlloc(count, x)), ...);
}
```

Comment: The inner `(` `)` can be removed I think.

Comment: error C3520: 'x': parameter pack must be expanded in this context. What version of C++ supports this ?

Comment: Yes, this answer does require C++17 or above because it uses a fold expression.

Answer (score 1):

The C++14 version: It handles 1 parameter and calls the function with 1 less parameter. Termination function, when there is only `count` left to break the recursion.

```
void checkedAlloc(size_t count) {}

template <typename T, class ... Ts>
void checkedAlloc(size_t count, T*& x, Ts&& ...args) {
  x = new T[count]();
  if(nullptr == x){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: not enough memory (%zux%zu bytes).\n\n", count, sizeof(T)); 
    exit(1);
  }
  checkedAlloc(count, args...);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/16jjsb

Let's go through the call graph for this main function:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass *A;
    int *B;
    float *C;
    checkedAlloc(20, A, B, C);
    delete[] A;
    delete[] B;
    delete[] C; 
}
```

`checkAlloc` gets called with 4 parameters (20, A, B, C).
This call allocs 20 elements of type of A and calls `checkAlloc` with 3 parameters (20, B, C).
This call allocs 20 elements of type of B and calls `checkAlloc` with 2 parameters (20, C).
This call allocs 20 elements of type of C and calls `checkAlloc` with 1 parameter (20).
This call ends up in the non template function in line 1 and does nothing.

Comment: What about : MyClass *A; checkedAlloc(20, A);

Comment: works also with your own types and you can mix types: https://godbolt.org/z/6TPrbK

Comment: Great then, this is exactly what I'm after. Thank you. Although I'm not clear yet on how the shaving of args works..

Comment: @WasfiJAOUAD added more explanation, is it clear now?

Comment: OK, got it. It's the split T*& x / Ts&& ...args that isolates the first arg and drops it from the list when recursion occurs. Thank you for a great answer.